# Is strict assertion on the returned object necessary in test cases?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am relatively new in writing "GOOD" unit test cases.

My Pojo class is :

```
public class User {

    private String userId;

    private String email;

    private String name;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My interface is :

```
public interface UserDao {

    List<User> getUsersByEmail(String email); 
}
```

My Testcase is ;

```
public class UserDaoTest {

    private UserDao userDao;
    @Test
    public final void testUsersGetByEmailFunctional()
    {
        final String email="test@gmail.com";
        List<User> usersByEmail = userDao.getUsersByEmail(email);
        Assert.assertNotNull(usersByEmail);
        for(User user : usersByEmail)
        {
            Assert.assertEquals(user.getEmail(), email);
        }
    }

    /**
     * NOTE : Consider that User.equals() method is not available due to other constraints 
     */
    @Test
    public final void testUsersGetByEmailStrict()
    {
        final String email="test@gmail.com";
        final String expectedName="xxx";
        final String expectedUserId="123";
        List<User> usersByEmail = userDao.getUsersByEmail(email);
        Assert.assertNotNull(usersByEmail);
        for(User user : usersByEmail)
        {
            Assert.assertEquals(user.getEmail(), email);
            Assert.assertEquals(user.getName(), expectedName);
            Assert.assertEquals(user.getUserId(), expectedUserId);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is, which test case is most appropriate?

http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/05/unit-testing-best-practices-junit-reference-guide/

The quote says,

> **Don’t make unnecessary assertions**
>
> **Remember, unit tests are a design specification of how a certain
>   behavior should work, not a list of observations of everything the
>   code happens to do.**
>
> Do not try to Assert everything just focus on what you are testing
>   otherwise you will end up having multiple testcases failures for a
>   single reason, which does not help in achieving anything.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit test usually means while-box testing. So, you should know your code and test what it does that it should do. If the `getUsersByEmail` is responsible to load data into email/name/id fields, then you should assert. If it delegates the loading to a different tested method, then you don't need to retest it again. Ideally - any logical change (I mean not refactoring) in the main code should break exactly one unit test.

The `assertNotNull(usersByEmail)` is unnecessary assertion, because if it is null, you'll get NPE in the next line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since you mentioned assertNotNull(usersByEmail) is unnecessary, I have a question. Can the test case by itself throw an exception. Ideally if a test case fails, I assumed it should be because of the assertions and not by the test case itself. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @TariqSulaiman usually a test method signature is `@Test public void testSomething() throws Exception`. Any exception thrown during a test makes it red.